# Команда для тг бота,не работает

Tags: python, telebot

Я создал кастомную команду для своего бота в тг,написал код по которому на команду бот должен отправлять сообщение(я добавил комманду через BotFather),но бот ничего не пишет и никак не реагирует:(
Если что команда /list

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Привет,что есть на выбор?")
    button2 = types.KeyboardButton("Как тобой пользоваться?")
    markup.add(button1,button2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, {0.first_name},что сегодня послушаем?.".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Привет,что есть на выбор?':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Ну смотри сам")
       elif message.text == 'Как тобой пользоваться?':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Ты можешь нажимать на кнопки")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['list'])
def list(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    list1 = types.KeyboardButton('На фон')
    markup.add(list1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Вот что есть на выбор✔'.format(reply_markup=markup))
```

print('Started')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить `await` к команде `bot.send_message`

То есть будет как то так

```
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Вот что есть на выбор✔'.format(reply_markup=markup))
```

Comment: `@bot.message_handler(commands=['list'])
async def list(message):
 markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
 list1 = types.KeyboardButton('На фон')
 markup.add(list1)
 await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Вот что есть на выбор✔'.format(reply_markup=markup))`
все ровно не реагирует

Comment: Перед всеми `bot.send_message` нужно добавить, я это имел ввиду

Comment: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'message' was never awaited
  task(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback